On minimal eigenvalue
Is it true that $\min\left(\lambda_{\min}(M_{12}),\lambda_{\min}(M_{13}),\lambda_{\min}(M_{23})\right) \le \frac{7}{20}$ where $M_{ij}$ is the matrix obtained by selecting the entries at the intersections of the $i$-th and $j$-th rows and columns of $
M = \mathbf{x}_{1}\mathbf{x}_{1}^{\top} + \mathbf{x}_{2}\mathbf{x}_{2}^{\top},
$ for all $\mathbf{x}_{1}, \mathbf{x}_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $\|\mathbf{x}_{1}\| = \|\mathbf{x}_{2}\| = 1$?
Any helpful answer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Do you have an example where the minimum is larger than $\frac{1}{3}$?

I too find numerical examples up to $\frac{1}{3}-10^{-33}$ and never larger than $\frac{1}{3}$. They have $-10^{-16} < \langle\mathbf{x}_1|\mathbf{x}_2\rangle < 10^{-16}$, suggesting a proof of optimality might go through $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ orthogonal.

$\mathbf{x}_1 = (1,1,0)/\sqrt{2}$, $\mathbf{x}_2 = (1,-1,-2)/\sqrt{6}$ give a minimum value of exactly $1/3$.

I can prove that $\min{\det(M_{12}), \det(M_{23}), \det(M_{13})} \leq 1/3$, but it's not immediately obvious to me whether or not this can be used to get the desired inequality.

@NathanielJohnston I observe $\min{\mathrm{Tr}[M_{12}], \mathrm{Tr}[M_{13}], \mathrm{Tr}[M_{23}]} \leq 4/3$, acheived by your example, as is consistent with $\lambda_{\min} = \frac12 (\mathrm{tr} - \sqrt{\mathrm{tr}^2 - 4 \mathrm{det}})$.

@Rammus - Yep, the trace inequality comes quickly from the fact that $\mathrm{tr}(M_{12}) + \mathrm{tr}(M_{13}) + \mathrm{tr}(M_{23}) = 2\mathrm{tr}(M) = 4$. It all seems to suggest that optimum is attained when the eigenvalues are $1$ and $1/3$, but I'm having difficulty putting it together. E.g., what rules out $2 \times 2$ submatrices with eigenvalues near $1/\sqrt{3}$, $1/\sqrt{3}$?

By the way, the question has much of a quantum theory flavor. Is that the context in which it appeared?

@ClaudeChaunier  It would be interesting if quantum theory had the same flavor as this. Could you please provide any references in quantum theory that have this flavor? Thanks.

I think it is moreso that you are looking at normalized vectors and positive semidefinite matrices built from such vectors, which are fundamental objects in quantum theory. In the language of quantum theory you could see $\frac12 M$ as being the density matrix representation of preparing the pure quantum state $x_1$ with probability $1/2$ and preparing $x_2$ with probability 1/2. A nice, concise introduction to the language of quantum information is given in the book "Alice and Bob meet Banach", a PDF copy can be found on the first author's personal website.

$\newcommand\Vol{\mathop{\mathrm{Vol}}}\newcommand\tr{\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}}$The estimate on the sum of determinants is rewritten.
Here is the proof that one of the eigenvalues indeed does not exceed $1/3$;
Let $X$ be the matrix with columns $\mathbf x_1$ and $\mathbf x_2$ (writing $X=(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)$); then $M=XX^\top$. Therefore, $M_{ij}=X_{ij}X_{ij}^\top$, where $X_{ij}$ is the submatrix of $X$ with only $i$th and $j$th rows left.
We are to estimate $t_{ij}=\tr M_{ij}$ and $d_{ij}=\det M_{ij}$. The first one is simple, as
$$
  \sum t_{ij}=2\|\mathbf x_1\|^2+2\|\mathbf x_2\|^2=4.
$$
For the second, introduce the Gram matrix $\Gamma=X^\top X$ of the $\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2$ and use the Cauchy-Binet formula  to write
$$
  1\geq \Vol(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)^2=\det\Gamma=\det X^\top X=\sum_{(i,j)}\det X_{ij}^2=\sum_{(i,j)} d_{ij}.
$$
(Notice that the formula for the sum of traces can be also viewed as an instance of the same formula.)
Assume now that the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_{ij}$ of $M_{ij}$ is larger than $1/3$, for all $i,j$; then both eigenvalues of $M_{ij}$ lie on $(1/3,3d_{ij})$. Since the dunction $x+d_{ij}/x$ attains its maximum at both endpoints of the segment $[1/3,3d_{ij}]$, we have
$$
  t_{ij}<\frac13+3d_{ij},
$$
and hence
$$
  4=\sum t_{ij}<1+3\sum d_{ij}\leq 4,
$$
which is a contradiction.
Generalizations. 1. (Here was a wrong proof of the following conjecture, sorry; I still believe in it and will try to prove.)
Conjecture. Let $d\geq 2$ be an integer. Assume that $\mathbf x_1,\dots,\mathbf x_{d-1}$ are unit vectors in $\mathbb R^d$, and let $M=\sum \mathbf x_i\mathbb x_i^\top$. Let $M_i$ denote the submatrix of $M$ obtained by removing the $i$th row and the $i$th column. Then one of the $M_i$ has an eigenvalue not exceeding $1/d$.
This bound is achieved if $\mathbf x_1,\dots,\mathbf x_{d-1}$is any orthonormal base in the hyperplane orthogonal to the all-ones vector $\mathbf 1=(1,1,\dots,1)^\top$..  Indeed, in this case $M=I-\frac1d\mathbf 1\mathbf 1^\top$, and the least eigenvalue of each $M_i$ is $1/d$.
2. This is to partially answer a (now deleted) question by the OP on what happens in $\mathbb R^4$.
A similar method works id $\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2$ are unit vectors in $R^4$. In this case, we have six matrces of the form $M_{ij}$, with
$$
  \sum_{(i,j)}d_{ij}\leq 1 \quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{(i,j)}t_{ij}=6.
$$
Now, if $\lambda_0$ is the minimmal eigenvalue, then we again have $t_{ij}\leq \lambda_0+d_{ij}/\lambda_0$, hence
$$
  6=\sum_{(i,j)}t_{ij}\leq 6\lambda_0+\frac1{\lambda_0}\sum_{(i,j)}d_{i,j}\leq 6\lambda_0+\frac1{\lambda_0},
$$
whence $\lambda_0\leq \frac12-\frac1{2\sqrt3}$ (since it could not happen that all eigenvalues are at least $\frac12+\frac1{2\sqrt3}$).
I am, however, unaware of whether this estimate is sharp.

I have added a proof of the $d$-dimensional generalization.

@Jasmine I am unsure of what  result would you expect from the method  in the general setup…

I realized that the ikey estimate becomes more transparent by means of the Cauchy--Binet formula, see edits. I have also added an estimate for $\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2\in\mathbb R^4$, but I do not know whether it is sharp.

Upper; sorry, edited.

Thank you for your answer. What if $M = x_1 x_1^\top + x_2 x_2^\top$, for all $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $|x_1| = |x_2| = 1$  and $\langle x_1, x_2 \rangle = 0$? Thanks!

What if $
M = \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\top} + \mathbf{y} \mathbf{y}^{\top} + \mathbf{z} \mathbf{z}^{\top}
$
for all $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^5$ with $|\mathbf{x}| = |\mathbf{y}| = |\mathbf{z}| = 1$? Thanks.

Sorry, I think now you can think a bit by yourself. Here, pne post is usually for one Q+A, not for such a large thread.

How did you obtain $\det\Gamma=\det XX^\top$? Thanks.

That was a typo; now corrected, thanks.

Why did you obtain $$
d_i\geq \lambda_i\cdot \left(\frac{t_i-\lambda_i}{d-2}\right)^{d-2}
$$ rather than the opposite direction using the AM-GM inequality? Thanks.

Oh, you are right! So *this * generalization is not proved yet, I will edit the answer. (Anyway, there is no need in commenting at both posts...)

Then how would the method work for $M = \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^\top + \mathbf{y}\mathbf{y}^\top + \mathbf{z}\mathbf{z}^\top$ for  $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^5$ with $|\mathbf{x}| = |\mathbf{y}| = |\mathbf{z}| = 1$? Thanks.
