On a combinatorial inequality
Is it true that
\begin{gather}
\min\left(\lambda_{\min}(M_{12}), \lambda_{\min}(M_{13}), \lambda_{\min}(M_{14}), \lambda_{\min}(M_{15}), \lambda_{\min}(M_{23}), \\ \lambda_{\min}(M_{24}), \lambda_{\min}(M_{25}), \lambda_{\min}(M_{34}), \lambda_{\min}(M_{35}), \lambda_{\min}(M_{45})\right) \leq \frac{2}{25}
\end{gather}
where $M_{ij}$ is the matrix obtained by deleting the $i$-th and $j$-th rows and columns of
$$
M = \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\top} + \mathbf{y} \mathbf{y}^{\top} + \mathbf{z} \mathbf{z}^{\top}
$$
for all column vectors $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^5$ with $\|\mathbf{x}\| = \|\mathbf{y}\| = \|\mathbf{z}\| = 1$?
Any helpful answer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I can't even see the inequality. I don't know if it's just me, though.

No, and I'm on a computer. The last thing I see is $\lambda_{\min}(M_{25}), \lambda_{\min}(M$.

is it true in any corner cases? e.g.when x=y=z the spectrum is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403614/eigenvalues-of-outer-product-matrix-of-two-n-dimensional-vectors. and so we indeed get it there.

here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926194/how-to-diagonalize-the-sum-of-outer-products, they go over a boostrapping process that might be helpful.

@ThomasKojar If it is true for corner cases, how would you prove it is true in general? And could you see the combinatorial aspect of the question? Thanks

@Jasmine Not yet, hopefully soon.

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477724

@IlyaBogdanov How does "$\det\Gamma=\det XX^\top$" in your answer to that question hold? Thanks.

@IlyaBogdanov Why did you obtain "$
d_i\geq \lambda_i\cdot \left(\frac{t_i-\lambda_i}{d-2}\right)^{d-2}
$" rather than the opposite direction using the AM-GM inequality in your answer to that question? Thanks.

@IlyaBogdanov  Since that "was a wrong proof" for $M_{ij}$'s that have more than 2 eigenvalues, how would that method work for finding an answer to this question? Thanks.

The number in the question was changed from $9/20$ to $2/25$ without any notice on that. And after the previous version was answered…

@IlyaBogdanov  Hello, did you see that the comment regarding the 2/25 bound was posted long before the update to this question? Why couldn't the comment regarding the 2/25 bound serve as a notice? Best regards

@IlyaBogdanov  Would that approach in your answer work for showing the updated bound, or do you have any other ideas for showing it? Thanks.

@Jasmine where are these specific rational numbers coming from? Simulations? Guesses? The literature? And why that specific change? Can you please give some plain-language insight on it?

@Jasmine I don't know what you mean. That's not helpful for my question.

@DavidRoberts  Wouldn't proving the sharp bound be harder? Would the approach in Ilya's answer work for showing the updated bound? Without a bound change, how would one know the limit of a method or approach?

@DavidRoberts  Do you have any method or approach to prove or disprove the inequality in the posted question?

@Jasmine your repeated questions seem very odd to me, and they aren't addressing the question. It doesn't seem like the actions of someone who is seriously engaging in the purpose of the site, and frankly sounds like someone has a AI-driven bot that's trying to experiment with MO to ask questions, but has a very narrow set of actions.

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\Vol{\mathop{\mathrm{Vol}}}$Okay, this really seems not that straigntforward to generalize the previous answer here. However, here is the method which seems to work (and which seemingly is generalizable). This is more or less the same computation  written in a more appropriate language.
Let $X$ be the matrix with columns $\mathbf x$, $\mathbf y$ and $\mathbf z$ (writing $X=(\mathbf x,\mathbf y,\mathbf z)$); then $M=XX^\top$. Denote by $\Gamma=X^\top X$ the Gram matrix of the vectors $\mathbf x$, $\mathbf y$, and $\mathbf z$.
It is known that, for any $n\times k$ matrix $A$ and any $k\times n$ matrix $B$ with $n\geq k$, the characteristic polynomials of $AB$ and $BA$ are related by $\chi_{AB}(x)=x^{n-k}\chi_{BA}(x)$, where $\chi_A(x)=\det(xI-A)$. Therefore, in our situation we have
$$
  \chi_M(x)=x^2\chi_\Gamma(x).
$$
Next, one can see that
$$
  \frac{\d^2}{\d x^2}\chi_M(x)=2\sum_{i<j} \chi_{M_{ij}}(x).
$$
To see this, in the left-hand side, consider the summands where the two operators $\d/\d x$  are applied to the fixed linear terms on the diagonal of $xI-M$; the sum of all those is exactly $\chi_{M_{ij}}(x)$.
To summarize,
$$
  p(x):=\sum_{i<j}\chi_{M_{ij}}(x)=\frac12(x^2\chi_\Gamma(x))''=10x^3-18x^2+\alpha x-\beta,
$$
where $\beta=\det\Gamma=\Vol(\mathbf x,\mathbf y,\mathbf z)^2\leq 1$.
Notice that $x^2\chi_\Gamma(x)$ has only real root; hence $p(x)$ has only real roots $\lambda_1\leq \lambda_2\leq\lambda_3$. Notice that  for some $i<j$ we have $\chi_{M_{ij}}(\lambda_1)\geq 0$, hence the smallest eigenvalue of $M_{ij}$ does not exceed $\lambda_1$. So, we are interested in estimating $\lambda_1$.
We have
$$
  \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=\frac 95, \quad 
  \frac1{10}\geq \frac\beta{10}=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\geq \lambda_1^2\left(\frac95-2\lambda_1\right),
$$
so $20\lambda_1^3-18\lambda_1^2+1\geq 0$. Since $\lambda_1\leq 3/5$, we get that $\lambda_1$ does not exceed the second largest root of $20x^3-18x^2+1$, which is approx. $0.285$. In particular, $\lambda_1\leq 9/20$ with a large gap.

I do not understand  the question.

Did you notice that $\lambda_1$ is the smallest root?

What if the number on the right-hand side of the inequality in the question is 2/25? Thanks.
